# AMSTHM package in Chapters

Tags: theorems, amsthm

While writing a report for thesis submission I have divided the chapters into separate `.tex` files but I have to use the `amsthm` package in the chapters. I included the package in the main `.tex` file, but it is not working; I also tried to include the package in the individual chapters, but still it is not working. Can someone guide me about this?

In the main file, I input the chapters using the command

```
\input{chapters/chapter_1}
```

In `chapter_1.tex` I have to write the proofs of the theorem.

I used the package in `main.tex` but it is not working there. So I included the package in `chapter_1.tex` (name of chapter 1 `.tex` file) but the message showing is "can be used only in preamble".

main file

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{Sample}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\input{sample_1}

\end{document}
```

given below is the code of the chapter

`````
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{lemma}
Lemma statement.
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}
Suppose D is a $(v, k, \lambda)$-difference set. There are $k(k-1)$ ordered
pairs $(r_1, r_2)$, with $r_1$, $r_2$ distinct elements of $D$, and therefore $k(k-1)$ differences $r_1$ - $r_2$ in the multiset $\Delta$. However, since $D$ is a difference set, each of the $v - 1$ non-identity elements of $G$ appears
exactly $\lambda$ times among the elements listed in $\Delta$. 
\end{proof}
````
`````

Comment: \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\usepackage{amsthm} %here it can be used only in preamble

Comment: Please provide something that others can copy and test as is. As your question sits right now, we have no idea what you are actually doing.

Comment: You cannot define theorems or load packages in the included files, move those to `main`

Comment: In the 'proof envt '  can I use 'align' command?

Comment: Of course. Instead of asking, why didn't you just try it? It either works or it does not.

Comment: Specifically, move those commands to `main`, before the `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Also, load the package before trying to establish a `newtheorem`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, let us first build an MWE with your given code snippets:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{Sample}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

%\input{sample_1}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{lemma}
Lemma statement.
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}
Suppose D is a $(v, k, \lambda)$-difference set. There are $k(k-1)$ ordered
pairs $(r_1, r_2)$, with $r_1$, $r_2$ distinct elements of $D$, and therefore $k(k-1)$ differences $r_1$ - $r_2$ in the multiset $\Delta$. However, since $D$ is a difference set, each of the $v - 1$ non-identity elements of $G$ appears
exactly $\lambda$ times among the elements listed in $\Delta$. 
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

which results in the first error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.15 \usepackage
                {amsthm}
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

As you can see in line 15 is the error: command `\usepackage` could only be used in the preamble. So let us move it into the preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\title{Sample}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

%\input{sample_1}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{lemma}
Lemma statement.
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}
Suppose D is a $(v, k, \lambda)$-difference set. There are $k(k-1)$ ordered
pairs $(r_1, r_2)$, with $r_1$, $r_2$ distinct elements of $D$, and therefore $k(k-1)$ differences $r_1$ - $r_2$ in the multiset $\Delta$. However, since $D$ is a difference set, each of the $v - 1$ non-identity elements of $G$ appears
exactly $\lambda$ times among the elements listed in $\Delta$. 
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

It compiles with one warning (correct, no author given!) and no errors.

It is better to also move the definitions for `theorem`, `corollary` and `lema` into the preamble, so we can use this definitions in all chapters ...

Therefore we get the final code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm} % <=================================================
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma} % <==================================

\title{Sample}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

%\input{sample_1}
\begin{lemma}
Lemma statement.
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}
Suppose D is a $(v, k, \lambda)$-difference set. There are $k(k-1)$ ordered
pairs $(r_1, r_2)$, with $r_1$, $r_2$ distinct elements of $D$, and therefore $k(k-1)$ differences $r_1$ - $r_2$ in the multiset $\Delta$. However, since $D$ is a difference set, each of the $v - 1$ non-identity elements of $G$ appears
exactly $\lambda$ times among the elements listed in $\Delta$. 
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

with the resulting second pdf page:

[image: second page]